# What is use of UIHint attribute in MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-uihint

Can anyone please explain me what is the use of UIHint attribute in MVC . Why do we need this. and when and how to use . Thanks

Comment: What have you read about it so far that was confusing?  What have you tried?  This isn't a good place to ask for information that is already in the documentation.

Comment: UIHint is a very important feature and sadly, the documentation of this is poor and there is no much clear articles or examples in the internet.

Answer (score 94):

[UIHintAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.aspx) Specifies the template or user control that Dynamic Data uses to display a data field.

This is the MSDN description of UIHintAttribute. It firstly introduced for Dynamic Data applications and ASP.NET MVC also adapted it.

If you annotate a property with UIHint attribute and use `EditorFor` or `DisplayFor` inside your views, ASP.NET MVC framework will look for the specified template which you specified through `UIHintAttribute`. The directories it looks for is:

For `EditorFor`:

> ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates
>
> ~/Views/Controller_Name/EditorTemplates

For `DisplayFor`:

> ~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates
>
> ~/Views/Controller_Name/DisplayTemplates

If you are on an area, it applies to your area like above as well.

Here is the usage sample:

```
public class Person { 

    [UIHint("Poo")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

MVC framework will look for partial view named `poo` under the specified directories if you try to output the model property with `EditorFor` or `DisplayFor` like below:

```
@model MyApp.Models.Person

<h2>My Person</h2>

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)` at the end?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how you would create the "Poo" display template?

Comment: Yes, please demonstrate how to create poo :J

Comment: contents of poo.cshtml:
@model string

@{    
        <span class='poo'>@Model</span>
}

Comment: The `Name` property is a `string`. By default, `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)` looks for a `string` editor. To plug to a custom partial view editor, `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Name.cshtml` for instance, there are 2 options: `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, "Name")` or `[UIHint("Name")] public string Name { get; set; }`.

Comment: Plus one for 'Poo'...

Comment: A template is written like a view. Its model is the type and value passed to it to be displayed or edited.