# How @Html.EditorFor resolve or point to right template

Tags: asp.net-mvc

just read the article for how to work with template for re-usability from this url http://www.iminfo.in/post/mvc-multiple-checkboxes-select-in-html-table-bootstrap

this article show just we need to create a template file in editor template folder with viewmodel name.

[image]

i just like to know how MVC @Html.EditorFor can point or pickup to right template file. need some guide line like how MVC resolve right template to pick up. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default templates are resolved by data type so if you use

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductViewModel)`it will use `EditorTemplates/ProductViewModel.cshtml` template.

However if you need to use a different template you can use an override of `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductViewModel, "yourTemplateName")` that accepts template name.

Additional option is to set a template by using [UIHint attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) on the property for example:

```
public class ComplexModel
{
    //will search for EditorTemplates/SomeProductModelTemplate.cshtml
    [UIHint("SomeProductModelTemplate")]
    public ProductViewModel ProductModel {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: can u redirect me to bit details discussion for this syntax `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductViewModel, "yourTemplateName")` and `[UIHint("SomeProductModelTemplate")]`

Comment: UIHint attribute: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196372/what-is-use-of-uihint-attribute-in-mvc

Comment: EditorFor template: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407414(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The template is resolved by data type.  In your example you have editor templates folder with a ProductViewModel template.  If you then create a view under the home directory using the `EditorFor` method with a ProductViewModel type then MVC will resolve the custom editor template.  Similarly, if you created a DateTime.cshtml file under editor templates then that would be used for `EditorFor` method calls with a DateTime parameter.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductViewModelItem) //will use the custom template
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StringItem) //will not use the custom template
```

You can also do the same with DisplayTemplates for `DisplayFor` or any of the other Html "for" helpers.